# printer queue not enabled

Tags: printing, menu

Printer doesn't work because "queue not enabled". Troubleshooting gives the following advice "To enable it, select the 'Enabled' checkbox in the 'Policies' tab for the printer in the printer administration tool. To start this tool, select System->Administration->Print Settings from the main menu."
But where do I find the "main menu"?

Answer (score 0):

CUPS is available at `http://localhost:631` and there you'll find the "Admin" tab. There are command line tools, too. `man -k cups`, but the web interface is easier.